# Xamarin IOS weird error, say Start() is not in Urho.application

Tags: xamarin.ios

10:40PM in Xamarin.iOS
this is the error :
[image]
but I know there is a Start() in application
what is wrong ?

part of the code you cant see in the picture :

```
using System;
using Urho.Audio;
using Urho.Gui;
namespace Brain_Entrainment 
{
public class IsochronicTones : Application
{
public float beat {get;set;}
public float Frequency {get;set}
public float Amplitude {get;set}
```

Comment: What is this class derived from? as that error suggests that whatever you're trying to derive from doesn't have a method called Start() to override.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Urho.Application/

Comment: I am deriving it from Application but it does have a Start().  check the link above

Comment: it has a protected start, and Urtho.Application is being derived here from Application, so i think it would need to be an internal protected for you to access it. if I were you I'd actually provide the full class above in your post, so we can see what you're deriving etc. as that Image doesn't provide the full story.

Comment: I added the part of the code you cant see

Comment: have you tried making sure that it's overriding the correct type of 'Application' by chanigng it to public class IsochronicTones : Urho.Application  ?

Comment: ok, I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly.  You are saying there are two Application.cs ? One is Application  and one is Urho.Application. I think I need to inherit from Application. I say that because of this example  https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/blob/master/FeatureSamples/Core/29_SoundSynthesis/SoundSynthesis.cs    the class inherts from Sample.cs and Sample.cs inhert from Application.  maybe I am not understand something

Comment: this is the sample.cs class : https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/blob/master/FeatureSamples/Core/Sample.cs

Comment: yep as part of xamarin there is a class called 'Application' that you can derive from, now if you look at your code above, you're deriving from Application, but in your solution on the right hand side, I can't see an Application.cs ... so it stands to reason that you might be inheriting from the internal 'Application' class object.

Comment: thanks that worked